# Установка jsquery

Tags: postgresql

Сначала выполнил

```
/data/jsquery$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет postgresql-contrib самой новой версии (10+193).
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 214 пакетов не обновлено.
```

затем

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION jsquery;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/jsquery.control": Нет такого файла или каталога
```

потом пробовал так

```
$ git clone https://github.com/postgrespro/jsquery.git
$ cd jsquery
$ make USE_PGXS=1
$ sudo make USE_PGXS=1 install
$ make USE_PGXS=1 installcheck
$ psql DB -c "CREATE EXTENSION jsquery;"
```

На команде make USE_PGXS=1 все упало с ошибкой

```
make USE_PGXS=1
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
yacc  jsquery_gram.y 
yacc: e - line 216 of "jsquery_gram.y", syntax error
%name-prefix="jsquery_yy"
^
make: *** [<встроенное>: jsquery_gram.c] Ошибка 1
```

поставил libpq-dev ... и т.д.
Есть-ли способ поставить-таки это расширение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `contrib` этого расширения закономерно нет (и не будет). `contrib` - только штатные расширения. А `jsquery` - полностью стороннее расширение и как со всеми сторонними расширениями вам необходимо его скомпилировать либо поставить уже кем-то предварительно собранный пакет.

Это именно `server-side` `extension`, поэтому заголовки сервера для сборки вам нужны будут гарантированно. У меня собирается относительно чисто, так что у вас вероятно не хватает ещё каких-то установленных пакетов. Попробуйте для начала с `postgresql-server-dev-`

---

Пакет этого расширения присутствует в официальном [репозитории PGDG](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) (PostgreSQL Global Development Group). Можно поставить оттуда

```
apt install postgresql-(version)-jsquery
```